# xcode error "is not signed with an apple submission certificate"

Tags: ios, xcode

I have tried EVERYTHING. 
From removing the certivicated, invalidating them, redownloading all certificates etc. 
Nothing seems to be working. 
I have been trying all resolutions (using search) but none seem to fix this problem for me. Does anyone have another suggestion? or something i can do to resolve this?

It is driving me nuts! :)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you trying with appstore certificate or adhoc certificate? also you want to submit app or for adhoc distribution?

Answer (score 0):

Did you use the **iPhone Configuration Utility** to better control which profiles are installed on your mac?

If you have not used yet, you can download it for free [here](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1465)

> iPhone Configuration Utility lets you easily create, maintain,
>   encrypt, and install configuration profiles, track and install
>   provisioning profiles and authorized applications, and capture device
>   information including console logs.

And here you can see your **Provisioning Profiles**

> ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles

Comment: Downloading it, just to see what else it can do, so thank you for that. But i forgot to mention i am submitting to the App Store, not provisioning to a device. Provisioning to a device works without any problem... so that would suggest something with the distribution certificate?

Comment: the "distribution certificate" is here ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles ? when you have create it , the app identifier (com.abcdefghi.myapp) is equal to the app identifier of your app ?

Comment: As of yet nothing came of this. The app identifier is the same.